# Rails 4.0: Save has_one association does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, has-one

i have got an rails application with a simple model:

**Customer has_one Address**

**Address belongs_to Customer**

new.html.erb

```html
<%=f .fields_for :address do |a| %>
  <%=a .label :street %>
    <br>
    <%=a .text_field :street %>
      <br>

      <%=a .label :number %>
        <br>
        <%=a .text_field :number %>
          <br>

          <%=a .label :zipcode %>
            <br>
            <%=a .text_field :zipcode %>
              <br>

              <%=a .label :city %>
                <br>
                <%=a .text_field :city %>
                  <br>

                  <%=a .label :country %>
                    <br>
                    <%=a .text_field :country %>
                      <br>
                      <% end %>
```

customer_controller.rb

```html
def create
  @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
  @customer.save
  redirect_to @customer
end
    
private
def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:ctype, :name, :dateOfBirth, :image, :custom1, :custom2, :custom3, :email, :phone, :mobilphone, :website, address_attributes:[:street, :number, :zipcode, :city, :country])
end
```

If I create a new customer with an address my address will not be saved :(

Can you may help me?

Comment: Do you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your model?

Comment: run `@customer.save!` what's the exception?

Comment: nope i dont use accepts_nested_attributes_for :/ not heared before I added it, do i need to rake:rollback -> rake db:migrate??, i dont get an exception...

Comment: @GeorgeKrause no, you don't have to redo your migration. Just read about `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in Rails guide and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address` in your customer model.

It should look like this, to tell rails that your code is actually updating other model.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :members
 has_one :address
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
is my class as you can see its already in...but it doesnt work :(

Comment: @GeorgeKrause You do have a customer form enclosing your address form, don't you? Also, could you try checking at the errors on the object `@customer` after save to see if there's something else preventing the save. To check errors http://liahhansen.com/2011/04/15/rails-console-show-error-messages-for-all-attributes.html